# Can't compile in Linux with curl - undefined reference

Tags: c++, linux, curl

I'm trying to compile a c++ sample in Linux(ubuntu) using curl lib but I'm getting undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'

Compile command:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl -I/usr/local/include -o request request.cpp
```

result:

```
/tmp/ccZwDiCf.o: In function 'main':<br>
request.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'<br>
request.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'<br>
request.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_perform'<br>
request.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_strerror'<br>
request.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_cleanup'<br>
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res!=CURLE_OK) 
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the `-lcurl` at the end of the compiler command. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/noobish-linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib/9966989#9966989

Comment: Also note that you don't need `-L/usr/local/lib` or `-I/usr/local/include`

Comment: also if its gonna be c++ code in there as you suggest you should use g++, not gcc

Comment: if you're linking curl statically (curl.a), you need to define `CURL_STATICLIB` before including the curl headers; not sure if this is your issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Just using -l at the end of the command works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Answer just to close this ask.

For resumate, you had to place the -lcurl option at the end of your compilation command line.

Answer (score 0):

When compilation is done with cmake, add these lines to your cmakelists.txt file

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(... ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(... ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```