# Boost.Regex linkage error LUbuntu 14.04 g++ 4.8.2

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost, linkage

Good morning!

I have problem with regular expressions in C++11.
I have Ubuntu Light 14.04 and this version of compiler:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I installed boost today using this three commands.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install aptitude
aptitude search boost
```

When i compile this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string text;
    regex pattern( "\\w* to \\w*" );
    return 0;
}
```

using this command:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

compiler returns:

```
/tmp/ccOdFz7f.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I read this topic: [linker error in boost regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446471/linker-error-in-boost-regex)
and used this command:

```
g++ -I /usr/lib/boost/include -L /usr/lib/boost/lib main.cpp -lboost_regex-mt
```

but compiler returns:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also don't have /usr/lib/boost directory!!!

What should i change in this program or do in Ubuntu to use regular expressions from boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker cannot find the specified file.
Use `-lboost_regex` to link the library.

To locate the installed regex library, invoke `locate libboost_regex`, like this:

```
$ locate libboost_regex
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0
```

In my case it is installed into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory