# Static link of boost_regex library

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking, boost-regex

I wrote a program using boost_regex library(ver 1.33.1) in CentOS 5.2 environment.
I installed the Boost library with yum command.

My program accepts compiling with this set of options below:

> g++ -O2 -g -lm -lboost_regex main.cpp

However, this set of option goes wrong:

> g++ -static -O2 -g -lm -lboost_regex main.cpp

the error code is below:

```
/tmp/ccZ2Yn5g.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:254: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:254: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:254: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:254: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:254: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccZ2Yn5g.o:/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:254: more undefined references to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)' follow
/tmp/ccZ2Yn5g.o: In function `perl_matcher':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_common.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/tmp/ccZ2Yn5g.o: In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:43: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT: removing -g option did not help.

Comment: Libraries at the end of the compiler command. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/noobish-linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib/9966989#9966989

Comment: Removing `-g` means leaving out debugging info, which is not needed for linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmjd's answer was correct.

Actually, at the same time, I've got my solution from a Japanese website.

According to the answer, correct command was below:

```
g++ -static -O2 main.cpp -lm -lboost_regex -lpthread
```

That is what hmjd said.