# Undefine references on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS libssl libcrypto

Tags: c++, linker, ubuntu-12.04

I have got a series of errors I have added `-l ssl and -l crypto`. However I do not know which version library I need to install

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:48: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:49: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:50: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:52: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:55: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:56: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:48: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init'
/usr/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/openssl_init.hpp:49: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings'
```

There are numerous options such as

```
Note, selecting 'libss7-dbg' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssl0.9.8-dbg' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libss7-dev' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssl0.9.8' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libss2' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssm-dev' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssl' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssh-4' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssh-2-dev' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssh-2-doc' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssl1.0.0' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libsscm3' for regex 'libssl*'
Note, selecting 'libssl-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libssl-ocaml-dev-l8h98'
Note, selecting 'libssl-ocaml' instead of 'libssl-ocaml-l8h98'
Note, selecting 'libssreflect-ocaml' instead of 'libssreflect-ocaml-kevs8'
Note, selecting 'libssreflect-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libssreflect-ocaml-dev-kevs8'
Note, selecting 'python-libssh2' instead of 'python2.7-libssh2'
libss2 is already the newest version.
```

and

```
Note, selecting 'libcryptokit-ocaml' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcryptokit-ocaml-02n31' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcryptgps-ocaml-dev' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-blowfish-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-saltedhash-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-gcrypt-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcryptui' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-generatepassword-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-dh-gmp-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-cbc-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-dsa-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-dh-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl' for regex 'libcrypto*'
Note, selecting 'libcryptgps-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libcryptgps-ocaml-dev-1zmb9'
Note, selecting 'libcryptokit-ocaml' instead of 'libcryptokit-ocaml-02n31'
Note, selecting 'libcryptokit-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libcryptokit-ocaml-dev-02n31'

g++ -pthread -l ssl -lcrypto IpcManagerMain.cpp -o IpcManagerMain.o  -lentity++ -lpersistence++ -lplatform++ -lreflection++ -lmonitor++ -lmeta++ -lipc++ -lbroadcast++ -lutilities++ -L/usr/lib          -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_date_time -lboost_iostreams -lboost_program_options -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

There are more but I have shortened it. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please add the **exact** compiler call to your question.

Comment: I have found out that it is the order that I have put the flags in the -l ssl etc should be at the end thanks for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Noobish, linker errors when compiling against glib...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/noobish-linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the (imaginary) linker trying to link these modules:

```
link moda modb modc modd
```

The linker doesn't (for efficiency reasons) record all the symbols it has seen in `moda` to try to match them with symbols in `modb`. For example, if `moda` is a huge library, then the linking process becomes very slow (and memory consuming), if all symbols of `moda` are remembered throughout the whole process.

As a result, the linker always remembers only the (so far) missing symbols and tries to find them in the modules that come **afterwards**.  Note that this is only true for libraries. This is because objects of the same library/application may have circular dependency.

This means that missing symbols of `modb` for example, are searched for only in `modc` and `modd` and *not* in `moda` (again, if `moda`, `modc` and `modd` are libraries).

Therefore, if you have `modx` using symbols of `mody`, then you must mention `mody` *after* `modx` in the link command.

For example, if you have files `main.o`, `funcs.o` and `libmatrix.a`, then you need to write your link command like this:

```
gcc funcs.o main.o -lmatrix
```

otherwise, if you write `gcc -lmatrix funcs.o main.o`, the symbols of `libmatrix.a` will not be visible to `funcs.o` and `main.o`.