# Undefined reference to `ssh_new'

Tags: c, makefile, libssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Noobish, linker errors when compiling against glib…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/noobish-linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib)

I have the following Makefile:

```
remote: RemoteCMD.o sshlib.o
    g++ -L/usr/include/libssh -lssh RemoteCMD.o sshlib.o -o RemoteCMD

RemoteCMD.o: RemoteCMD.cpp
    g++ -c RemoteCMD.cpp

sshlib.o: sshlib.cpp
    g++ -c sshlib.cpp
```

sshlib.h includes libssh/libssh.h and sshlib.cpp includes sshlib.h.  When made I get:

```
g++ -L/usr/include/libssh -lssh RemoteCMD.o sshlib.o -o RemoteCMD
sshlib.o: In function `ssh::connect(char*, char*)':
sshlib.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `ssh_new'
```

I also double check where libssh.a is:

```
$> whereis libssh.a
libssh: /usr/include/libssh
```

I've also tried `-llibssh` and `-llibssh.a`.  Seems [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.ssh.libssh.general/1039) guy has a very similar unanswered question, too.

Comment: Libraries at the end. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/noobish-linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib/9966989#9966989

Comment: .....thanks! Make it an answer, and I'll accept

Comment: Don't know if this helps someone else...
Still I had some problem, -llibssh at the end gave me "cannot find -llibssh"
Much trail and error, gave me this line.
g++ -I/usr/include/libssh  test.cpp -o test.o -lssh