# Creating makefile with pthreads

Tags: c, makefile, pthreads, posix, semaphore

I want to create a makefile that supports posix semaphores.
That is what I've got so far:

```
CFLAGS=-g -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600
LDFLAGS=-pthread 
CC=gcc
OBJECTS=MsgQueueMain.o MsgQueue.o Queue.o MyMalloc.o
TARGET=MsgQueueMain

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

include depends

depends:
    $(CC) -MM $(OBJECTS:.o=.c) > depends

clean:
    rm ./$(TARGET) *.o
```

For some reason, I'm getting "undefined reference" for all calls to semaphore.h api functions.

Comment: This is probably not related to your prolem, but you need `-pthread` when compiling and linking, so you should add it to `CFLAGS` as well.

Answer (score 6):

You need to link with the `rt` or `pthread` library. From [man sem_destroy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_destroy) reference page:

> Link with -lrt or -pthread.

Add to the end of the compiler command as [order is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966959/linker-errors-when-compiling-against-glib/9966989#9966989) (unsure if order is important for `-pthread` as this defines some macros and adds `-lpthread`).

As commented by [Vlad Lazarenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405725/vlad-lazarenko) the `LDFLAGS` is *not* part of your `TARGET`. Change to:

> $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

Comment: His problem is that `LDFLAGS` is not specified in his `$(TARGET)` building command and not because he doesn't know that `-pthread` is need...

Comment: @VladLazarenko, well spotted. I completely missed that.